# Alternative to executeBatch in jdbc with different failure handling?

Tags: jdbc

executeBatch update does not continue executing the rest of the commands if theres a failure in one of the execution. Is there anyway or any alternative to executeBatch, wherein even if a command fails to execute, still the rest of the commands are successfully executed. Not using executeUpdate since it takes a lot of time and executes query one by one.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says this:

An exception thrown when an error occurs during a batch update operation. In addition to
the information provided by SQLException, a BatchUpdateException provides the update
counts for all commands that were executed successfully during the batch update, that is, all
commands that were executed before the error occurred. The order of elements in an array of
update counts corresponds to the order in which commands were added to the batch.
**After a command in a batch update fails to execute properly and a BatchUpdateException is
thrown, the driver may or may not continue to process the remaining commands in the
batch.** If the driver continues processing after a failure, the array returned by the method
BatchUpdateException.getUpdateCounts will have an element for every command in the
batch rather than only elements for the commands that executed successfully before the error.
In the case where the driver continues processing commands, the array element for any command
that failed is Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED.

So as I understand it depends on jdbc-driver you work with.

Probably a better solution would be to find a reason of the problem and fix it?

Comment: Yes but the program that i am working on inserts millions of records. Also it will be a better error handling feature if the program itself handles the flow and allows the execution of rest of the batch commands if theres a failure. The jdbc driver i work with does not support processing after a failure. Hence i need an alternative or a way to make executeBatch work. Thanks :)

Comment: If you really are going to insert millions of records, I would recommend you using a special dabase-vendor specific tools that allows to load data into the db server. Your program only may prepare data of special format. Then, you apply the chosen tool.